# merge duplicate (row group) in rdlc report

Tags: sql-server, report, rdlc

I have 3 Database tables named patient, test and groups

The patient table have patient name and test_Id columns

the test table has `test_id`, `test_name` and `group_id`

groups table has `group_Id` and `group_Name`,

and i made SQL query that brings all data in the 3 table considered the relationships between the 3 tables.

and this is the result of my query

```
patient_name     test_name              group_id

A                  test1                1
A                  test2                1
A                  test3                1
B                  test4                2
B                  test5                2
```

I want the result to be like this

```
Patient_name    Test_name                  group_id

A               test1, test2, test3          1

B               test4, test5                 2
```

This is my example, i tried to make Join with Lookupset functions

It was succeeded but repeating the row  with test numbers- if the patient has 3 tests, rows will be repeated 3 time

,like that

```
A                       test1, test2, test3          1

A                       test1, test2, test3          1

A                       test1, test2, test3          1

B                       test4, test5                 2

B                       test4, test5                 2
```

I only want the result to be in one row for each patient.

Sorry for making it long question but i wanted to make my case's clear.

Comment: Please post queries to create the table(s) and insert some sample data + the requested result according to the sample data

Comment: this is the database query

Answer (score 0):

USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [NewTest]    Script Date: 08/04/2018 15:36:09 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [NewTest] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'NewTest', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewTest.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'NewTest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewTest_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [NewTest].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO

ALTER DATABASE [NewTest] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO

Answer (score 0):

This is the query
SELECT     dbo.patient.patientId, dbo.patient.PName, dbo.test.testName, dbo.groups.groupName, dbo.groups.groupId
FROM         dbo.patient INNER JOIN
                      dbo.patientDetails ON dbo.patient.patientId = dbo.patientDetails.patientID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.test ON dbo.patientDetails.testId = dbo.test.testId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.groups ON dbo.test.groupId = dbo.groups.groupId

this is the result of my query 
Patient_ID      Name      Test    Gruop_name
1             patient1   Test1     Group1
1             patient1   Test2     Group1
1             patient1   Test3     Group1
2             patient2   Test4     Group2
2             patient2   Test5     Group2
 I want the Result to be Like that
Patient_ID       Name         Test               Group_name
1               patient1     Test1,Test2,Test2     Group1
2               patient2     Test3,Test4           Group1

Answer (score 0):

Good day Sameh Awwad,

This is thread is a bit mess. I will try to explain what I understand and answer the question which I understand.

First, I recommend to remove the extra "answers" where you tried to provide more information. I realize that stackoverflow interface is very poor and you cannot add comments which include formatted code. We have only the option to add answer or simple one-line comment. But these are obviously not answers.

In addition there was no reason to post these queries. We don't need the query to create the database and I did not asked for this. We need the queries to create the original tables that are relevant to the question, queries to insert the sample data, and the query that you used to get the interim result.

As much as I understand you have a query that brings you the following result:

```
patient_name     test_name              group_id

A                  test1                1
A                  test2                1
A                  test3                1
B                  test4                2
B                  test5                2
```

and you want to take this interim result and get the following final result:

```
Patient_name    Test_name                  group_id

A               test1, test2, test3          1
B               test4, test5                 2
```

We can continue from here, but this is not the best approach. Maybe we can provide better solution that take us directly from the original data to the final result.

Anyhow, for your current request if you are using SQL Server 2017 and above then you can use the function STRING_AGG which gives you very simple solution

```
/*************************************************** DDL+DML */
-- these queries will create the interim result

drop table if exists T;
create table T(patient_name nvarchar(10),test_name nvarchar(10),group_id int)
GO

insert T (patient_name,test_name,group_id)
values 
('A','test1',1),
('A','test2',1),
('A','test3',1),
('B','test4',2),
('B','test5',2)
GO

SELECT patient_name,test_name,group_id
FROM T
GO

/************************************************ solution */
SELECT patient_name,group_id,
    STRING_AGG(test_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by patient_name,group_id,test_name)
from T
group by patient_name,group_id
GO
```

[You can get more information from this post in my blog](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/152/Unsplit-Using-For-XML-with-group-by-columns.aspx), which also include solution for older versions of SQL Server